# AngularJS: append param to url and refresh page

Tags: angularjs, append, refresh, param

How can I do this in Angular:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "/?id = 123";
```

So append new paramater to the end of the url and refresh the page(without loading it from cache).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$location` for that.

Example: `$location.search('id','123)`

That is going to append `?id=123` to the current page url and do a soft refresh.

Then to do a hard refresh you can do `location.reload()`

Comment: $location.search('id','123') works as expected but after doing location.reload(), the appended params is removed from the url.

Comment: Are you using ui-router for routing?

Comment: No, I'm using ngRoute

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use $window :

```
$window.location.href = $location.path() + "/?id = 123";
```

Or use $location :

```
$location.url($location.path() + "/?id = 123");
```

The results are same, only view is reload by angular, this is not a force refresh by the browser.